# B is the set of bitstrings s of size 8. Which is a function from B to N?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

f(s) is the position of a 0 in s

f(s) is the number of 0's in s

f(s) is the position of the first 0 in s

These are the options. Can someone help me understand what this is asking? I really have no clue and I do not recall learning about this is class.

Answer (score 1):

To be a function, you need to assign a single value to each element of the domain.  In your case, there are $2^8$ strings in $s$.  For the first one, if the string is $a=01010101$, what is $f(a)$?  You can't give a single answer, so this is not a function.  For the next two, think about the same question-can I give a clear value to the function for every one of the bitstrings?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is asking, "What is the definition of a function?", amongst other things. To be a function, it must be continuous, and if we take the first choice that your provided, we need to ask ourselves, "What happens when I take f(1)? f(2)? f(0)?" We see that when we take any of these three questions (again, regarding the first choice), we have a discontinuous function, which is not a function. Likewise, we can see something very similar to the third choice that you provided.

I believe process of elimination works here, and I will leave it up to you to see why this second choice is in fact a function. :)

If you have any difficulty, after a fair share of effort, I would be glad to help!

Comment: There is no need for continuity in a function.  All you need is to have an unambiguous value for the function at all points in the domain.  In fact, no function into $\Bbb N$ is continuous unless it is constant.